# Why do we use 'self.' before calling a value?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am a silly beginner of iOS xcode. When I am learning objective-C 'self.' is mostly used while searching example codes from others on the internet. But, when we have already synthesized the value it is just the same whether there is 'self.' or not, right?

I wonder when the self is used for a specific situation. Please help me clarify :)

Comment: Try to learn first 'Property' in Objective C . You will easily get why we use self.

Comment: self. is keyword similar like in 'this' keyword in JAVA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `self.myProperty` is shorthand for `[self myProperty]`. So it's using the accessor method to retrieve the value.

Accessing the ivar directly (omitting `self.`) is not the same. For example a subclass could override the `myProperty` method, changing the returned value. Another common case is lazy initialization: The property getter sets up the value in the first access.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in `property` and `instance variable` (or `ivar`).

Using `self.myVariable` you are working with a ***property***, using `myVariable` you are working with ***ivar***. The rule to remember here is this: **"Never work with `ivar` in your app except of init methods cases".** If you are a beginner, just use `self` everywhere in your code, and you will be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! :) I will keep using self everywhere